# bottom container needs to come above keyboard when we click on any input field in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard, js-scrollintoview

Here is my bottom container now I want that whenever the user clicks on an input field this container goes above the keyboard. I have the user scrollIntoView to do this but it shifted the entire page upwards. I want that only the container goes above the keyboard.  I want to do this on website.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'
    
    function App() {
      const ref = useRef(false);
      return (
        <div style = {{position: 'fixed', left: '0px', bottom:'0px', backgroundColor: 'red', overflow:'auto', height:'50%'}} >
            <div>
           <div> Enter your name</div>
            <input
            type ='text'
            onChange ={()=>
              ref?.current?.scrollIntoView()
              
            
            }
            />
            <div style ={{position: 'fixed', left: '0px', bottom:'0px' , backgroundColor: 'green', height:'5%'}} ref={ref} >
              our Bottom container
              </div>
              
              </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Please show us what bottom container, what page, or what code you have wrote so that we can debug. We can't magically know what to do if you don't give us your details. You might want to check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam I have re-reviewed my question. please provide possible help.